# Dynamically rendering values in a reactjs array map

Tags: reactjs

I am building a login form and I am dynamically rendering the input fields using reactjs array map. However, I need to get each user input via the input values. I use states to get the values of each user, but I don't know how to do it dynamically.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';

const loginForm = [ 
   {
       name: 'email',
       placeholder: 'Email address',
       type: 'text'
   }, 
   {
       name: 'password',
       placeholder: 'Password',
       type: 'password'
   }
]

export class Login extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        email: '',
        password: ''
    }

    this.getInput = this.getInput.bind(this);
}

getInput = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name] : [event.target.value]
    });
}

resetForm = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        email: '',
        password: ''
    });
}

validateForm = (email,password) => {

    if(email == "" || password == "") {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

render() {

    return (
        <div> 
            <form method="POST" onSubmit={event => this.Login(event)}>
                {loginForm.map( (form,index) => (

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type={form.type} name={form.name} className="form-control" placeholder={form.placeholder} value={this.state.form.name} onChange={event => this.getInput(event)}/>
                    </div>
                    ))
                }

                <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
            </form>

        </div>
       );
   }
}
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by `dynamically`...

Comment: there are perhaps 3 or 4 distinct problems with this code - but which one are you asking about? Short of rewriting the entire thing, I'm not sure anyone could truly help with this. See [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input 
                        type={form.type} 
                        name={form.name} 
                        className="form-control" 
                        placeholder={form.placeholder} 
                        value={this.state[form.name]} 
                        onChange={this.getInput}
                     />
```

Answer (score 0):

I just redid your code. And you're really close.

Just change the value in your `<input />` to the below:

`value={this.state[form.name]}`

The reason - your state looks like this.

```
state = {
   "email":["sample@email.com"],
   "password":["somethingsecure"]}
}
```

If you try to access `this.state.form.name` you'll notice that there is no form property in the object, so it will be undefined.

if `form.name` is `'email'` then you need to dynamically access like so:

`value={this.state[form.name]}` -> `value={this.state['email']}`